# Date.js formating to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, php, date, format, tostring

Hello my user can input date like 2/2/2008, but I need it in format 02/02/2008. How do i reformat it with date.js?

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("smth").value = Date.parse(smth, "dd/mm/yyyy").toString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

while parse works fine, toString outputs 02/00/2008? and if run it again on date 02/00/2008 I get 
01/00/2008.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: And not any of [these 41 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript/10119138#10119138) was what you want?

Comment: Sorry bout that. I searched few answers but I hadn't come across that one. Solution was MM instead of mm. Check the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to format with "dd/MM/yyyy"

`Date.parse("2/2/2008", "dd/mm/yyyy").toString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this case sensitive? mm for minutes, MM for months?

Comment: yes. That solved my problem. I should have read manuals better. my bad